# Using UPDLOCK without transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

The documentation states that `Specifies that update locks are to be taken and held until the transaction completes.` So if I'm not transactions is it pointless to add it to my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in SQL Server is done inside a Transaction. Whether you explicitly open a transaction by using key words `Begin Transaction` or you don't, if you don't explicitly open a transaction (A.K.A `Explicit Transaction`), sql server wraps your t-sql statements inside a transaction automatically also known as `Implicit Transactions`.

Now during a transaction (explicit or implicit) sql server will obtain some locks on the resources (tables, indexes etc), depending on what type of action is being taken, sql server obtain different types of locks (Shared Locks , Exclusive locks etc)

If you use UPDLOCK (Update lock) in your statement, it is an exclusive lock and other users will not be able to access the object(s) for the duration of your transaction (explicit or implicit).

Hence whether you use transactions (explicit transaction) or not (Implicit transaction) if you use the hint (UPDLOCK) in your statement you query will obtain exclusive locks and will lockout the object to you exclusively for the duration of your transaction.

Comment: thanks, the extra context on the implicit transactions was helpful.

Comment: An UPD lock is not exclusive. It is compatible with shared locks, but not other UPD locks or X locks. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172925(v=sql.110).aspx